# How to invoke a list of Task<T> by using Parallel

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, async-await, class-library

I've got a list of async calls that are lined up in specific order and it does not matter which one finishes first or last. All of these async Task returns Bitmaps. All of the async Task return a single Bitmap accept for one and it returns a list of Bitmaps List.

For testing purposes and me being able to get a better handle on the difference of using Parallel vs just Task I need someone to show me how to invoke each one of these async Task and set a local variable that contains a list of all the returned async results.

1. How to Parallel.ForEach of these task
2. How to retrieve the value of each completed task and set a local variable with the returned result.

---Code where I just await each Task one after another.

```
public async static Task<PdfSharp.Pdf.PdfDocument> RollUpDrawingsPDF(IElevation elevation)
{

    List<Bitmap> allSheets = new List<Bitmap>();

    var processedParts = new PartsProcessor.PartProcessor().ProcessParts(elevation);

    //elevation
    allSheets.Add(await ShopDrawing.Manager.GetElevationDrawing(elevation, true, RotateFlipType.Rotate90FlipNone));

    //door schedules, 3 schedules per sheet
    allSheets.AddRange(await ShopDrawing.Door.GetDoorSecheduleSheets(elevation, RotateFlipType.Rotate90FlipNone, 3));

    //materials list
    allSheets.Add(await MaterialsList.Manager.GetMaterialList(processedParts).GetDrawing());

    //optimized parts
    allSheets.Add(await Optimization.Manager.GetOptimizedParts(processedParts).GetDrawing());

    //cut sheet
    allSheets.Add(await CutSheet.Manager.GetCutSheet(processedParts).GetDrawing());

    return await PDFMaker.PDFManager.GetPDF(allSheets, true);
}
```

------**Code I'm tring to run in Parallel.ForEach however this isn't working but a starting place for help. For each returned task result I need to set the local variable of allSheets of that Parallel Task Result.**

```
    public async static Task<PdfSharp.Pdf.PdfDocument> RollUpDrawingsPDF(IElevation elevation)
{

    List<Bitmap> allSheets = new List<Bitmap>();

    var processedParts = new PartsProcessor.PartProcessor().ProcessParts(elevation);

    Task[] myTask = new Task[5];
    myTask[0] = ShopDrawing.Manager.GetElevationDrawing(elevation, true, RotateFlipType.Rotate90FlipNone);
    myTask[1] = ShopDrawing.Door.GetDoorSecheduleSheets(elevation, RotateFlipType.Rotate90FlipNone, 3);
    myTask[2] = MaterialsList.Manager.GetMaterialList(processedParts).GetDrawing();
    myTask[3] = Optimization.Manager.GetOptimizedParts(processedParts).GetDrawing();
    myTask[4] = CutSheet.Manager.GetCutSheet(processedParts).GetDrawing();



    var x = Parallel.ForEach(myTask, t => t.Wait());

    ////elevation
    //allSheets.Add(await );

    ////door schedules, 3 schedules per sheet
    //allSheets.AddRange(await);

    ////materials list
    //allSheets.Add(await );

    ////optimized parts
    //allSheets.Add(await );

    ////cut sheet
    //allSheets.Add(await );

    return await PDFMaker.PDFManager.GetPDF(allSheets, true);
}
```

**How would I implement the Parallel.ForEach for this body of code?**

****Discussion code example. How to return a List when other methods return one Bitmap****

```
async Task<Bitmap[]> RollUpHelper(IElevation elevation, PartsProcessor.ProcessedParts       processedParts)
            {
                return await Task<Bitmap[]>.WhenAll(

 ShopDrawing.Manager.GetElevationDrawing(elevation, true, RotateFlipType.Rotate90FlipNone),
                     //ShopDrawing.Door.GetDoorSecheduleSheets(elevation,RotateFlipType.Rotate90FlipNone, 3),
                     MaterialsList.Manager.GetMaterialList(processedParts).GetDrawing(),
                     MaterialsList.Manager.GetMaterialList(processedParts).GetDrawing(),
                     CutSheet.Manager.GetCutSheet(processedParts).GetDrawing()
                      );

            }
```

Comment: Do you definitely have to use `async` for this? If not, it's relatively easy to do this with `Parallel.Invoke()`

Comment: @MatthewWatson: If `GetDrawing()` is (correctly) async, yes.

Comment: @SLaks I forgot about the overload of [`Task.WhenAll()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194874.aspx) that returns an array of results - that's the one you were talking about of course.

Answer (score 6):

`Parallel.ForEach()` is for running multiple *synchronous* operations in parallel.

You want to wait for a number of *asynchronous* `Task`s to finish:

```
await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

Comment: Anyway you could offer a little code as to how I set the local variable allSheets. allSheets is a List<Bitmap>. Remember one of the task returns a List<Bitmap> and the other Task return just a single Bitmap.

Comment: Does this mean that I am going to need to loop the myTask[n] and get the result from each one and then add it to the local variable allSheest?

Comment: You could use a [`ConcurrentBag< List<Bitmap> >`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd381779.aspx) to store the returned results; it's ideal for when you only need an unordered set like that. You could write a wrapper function for the one that returns a `Bitmap` to turn it into a `List<Bitmap>` of length 1, so you can store that result too. You can pass the bag to a lambda for each task that calls the function you want and puts its return value into the bag.

Comment: @AlumCloud.Com: `await Task.WhenAll(tasks);` will return an array of `Bitmap`s.

Comment: The problem with this implementation is that one of the methods returns a List<Bitmap> and the rest return a Bitmap

Comment: Then you can call the non-generic `WhenAll()`, then `await` the tasks individually afterwards to get the results.  (since the `await WhenAll()` will have waited for them earlier, a later `await` will return instantly)

Answer (score 0):

To expand upon SLaks' answer:

[`Task.WhenAll()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194874.aspx) will return an array of all the results returned by the tasks it waited for, so you don't need to manage that yourself.

Here's an example where I use `string` instead of `Bitmap` as in your example. Note how one of the workers doesn't return a `List<string>` and I convert it to a `List<string>` with one item, to make it the same type as the others.

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Threading;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;

    namespace Demo
    {
        class Data
        {
            public string Value;
            public Data(string value) { Value = value; }
        }

        class Program
        {
            async Task<List<string>[]>  RunAsync()
            {
                return await Task.WhenAll
                (
                    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => 
                        new List<string> {Worker1(new Data("One"))}),

                    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => 
                        Worker2(new Data("Two"))),

                    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => 
                        Worker3(new Data("Three")))
                );

            }

            void Run()
            {
                var results = RunAsync().Result;

                // Now results is an array of List<string>, so we can iterate the results.

                foreach (var result in results)
                {
                    result.Print();
                    Console.WriteLine("--------------");
                }
            }

            string Worker1(Data data)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
                return data.Value;
            }

            List<string> Worker2(Data data)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(1500);
                return Enumerable.Repeat(data.Value, 2).ToList();
            }

            List<string> Worker3(Data data)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(2000);
                return Enumerable.Repeat(data.Value, 3).ToList();
            }

            static void Main()
            {
                new Program().Run();
            }
        }

        static class DemoUtil
        {
            public static void Print(this object self)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(self);
            }

            public static void Print(this string self)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(self);
            }

            public static void Print<T>(this IEnumerable<T> self)
            {
                foreach (var item in self)
                    Console.WriteLine(item);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: No; he's asking about async operations

Comment: You still aren't using asynchrony; this will deadlock.

Comment: @SLaks Oops missed the async... Seems ok now I think

Comment: Ok, let me give this a shot.

Comment: I've updated my original post. Is there anyway for the commented code to return correctly. Right now all the other methods return one Bitmap. The commented code returns a List<Bitmap>. Is there a way to do a .ToArray().

Comment: @AlumCloud.Com It's easy to turn a single item into a size-one list, but it's not easy to turn a list into a single item, so could you convert all the single bitmaps into size-one lists (like I do when calling `Worker1()` in my example). The overall result would then be an array of `List<Bitmap>` where some (most?) of the `List<Bitmap>` would only contain one item.